How do I Make background object (mannequin) transparent or immoveable/locked so I can design armour around it
How can I lock a wire frame mesh to the background and change the wire frame color? Is there a way to adjust the locked objects transparency?  

Hello, it's hard to understand, could you please show some screenshots?
